# Access Apache22 server installed on guestOS(FreeBSD) from Host(Win7)

Tags: apache-2.2, windows-7, freebsd, vmware-workstation

(I asked this question on SuperUser 3 days ago and had no answer...)

I would like to access my freshly installed apache server (via ports) on my FreeBSD guestOS from Windows 7. So I set my virtual network on VMWare to bridged, I edited the hosts file on my Windows, I opened a browser on Windows and tried to reach 192.168.0.13 (guest's address)... But still, I can't get to my index.html web page. Google says that it cannot connect to 192.168.0.13.
The only thing I can do to see my "It works!" page is

```
lynx localhost
```

on freeBSD.

I disabled my Windows firewall, I can ping my FreeBSD from my Windows, and my Windows from my FreeBSD.

What am I missing?

**EDIT:**

I have no proxy, and my httpd.conf file has been correctly edited.
Here it is : http://pastebin.com/w9Q7Tq26

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "can't get to my index.html". Does the browser time out? Do you have a proxy configured for the browser? FreeBSD's default configuration has no firewall, did you have one enabled that you disabled, what exactly do you mean by "disabled my firewalls" in relation to FreeBSD? How was Apache installed? Did you change it's configuration at all?

Comment: Is my question clearer now?

Comment: Try run command `lynx 192.168.0.13` from freebsd. Did you see "It works" page?

Comment: I get "unable to connect to remote host".

Comment: Sounds like something in `httpd.conf` is off. Can you scrub and dump it to something like http://pastebin.com ?

Comment: There we go: http://pastebin.com/w9Q7Tq26

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is FreeBSD firewall allowing EXTERNAL connections on port 80?
You have not specified that you've checked this in your question.

Also make sure you have bind your server not only to localhost:80, but to 192.168.0.13:80 or *:80 in general as well

Comment: Thank u! Now it works! I didn't know that I had to add *:80, I thought using localhost only would do the thing...
Thanks again :)